# SAS Visual Analytics Versioning Control using git

Tags: git, sas, atlassian-sourcetree

I am working on SAS VA (Web app server)to build some reports as per the requirement. I was asked to do version control for the reports I made in SAS VA using Source Tree.
Can any one help me in doing version control for SAS VA using Source Tree(git GUI) or any other preferred tools.

Comment: This sounds like you're looking for a tutorial on git, which is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: No it's a very deep question about using SAS VA and trying to have a versioning of the work done

Answer (score 0):

Up to my knowledge, source versioning of a Visual Analytics report are not possible via GIT, or any graphical front end of it, since every information regarding the report is embedded into SAS metadata that are saved into the metadaserver server.

These information are not directly available to the end user.

You could extract every information of your report from the metadataserver but you have to write a specific code and store it in a specific sets of structures. It's a very hard way to backup/version a report in this way.

You can try to save your report in the .SPK file, open it with 7ZIP like a normal zip file and lok for XML files that describe your report. I have studied the problem and found a way of see the source code of the report. In this way you can save XML data as a "SOURCE" of your report. To restore previous version you can just exchange sources. Be careful that is a delicate operation since I see that the xml is not intended to be modfied by hand.
ONCE you have modfied the SPK of your report, you can upload it back on the server to load the different version of your report.

You should also have a backup of the data since it's feasible that every modification in your dataset can lead to differences in the report.

Comment: I have edited the answer since I had new information that should be spread along SAS community

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will help now may be for people in future. you can replicate DI Studio SVN Version Control.. Similarly there are applications talk to GIT. Version Control might be possible for VA reports.

Comment: Unfortunately DI Studio is unable to manage VA report objects. It cannot checkin/out/import/export them so the SVN/CVS integration is unable to be used. SAS Management Console (smc) or the command line tools must be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest exporting the report(s) into a SAS package (SPK) and storing that in source control as a binary file. This can be scripted using the [SAS Promotion tools](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/bisag/68240/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1rpvy5m50aglkn1koi9dsbc3mpx.htm). In a rollback scenario you can import an earlier version of the exported spk.

As @pm2r has mentioned in their answer, the report is contained in another spk in the export and can be viewed. The "inner" spk will be named after the Metadata ID of the report.